# Is is possible to move the Orbit bullets inside the slides-container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using [the Orbit component of Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) and wondering if there's a way to move the bullets that appear below the slides into the content area of the slides themselves. Putting the bullets on top of the pictures, basically.

There are a number of [configuration variables available](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html#configuring-orbit), but none seem to address bullet positioning and I haven't been able to work out a way to do it in CSS.

Comment: JSfiddle with HTML & CSS please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a negative `margin-top` to the `orbit-bullets-container` class will achieve this e.g.

```
.orbit-bullets-container
{
    margin-top: -60px;
}
```

Adjust that value so it appears in the place you want it to be. You might want to add a `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` to put the content below the slider back down the page.

Comment: Alternatively, give it `position:relative` and `top : a negative value` and no padding/margin is needed.

Comment: I was just fiddling with the top margin when you posted. Thanks!